Is it ok to be running localhost on the server when deploying a full stack application?
I am wondering if I did my deployment correctly on AWS Lightsail with apache. I have built my react frontend and copied the files over to htdocs. The backend is running with localhost on port 4000. I open up port 4000 and the client files then access the api through port 4000. Is this ok? I also read some approaches using virtual hosts but I am not sure if I want that or not.

You typically run private services on private address spaces, like localhost (127.0.0.1, ::1) or unix domain sockets (which is often the same but better, because it's more efficient with less overhead). For public you expose them granularly using the reverse proxies or other front-end services. This publication is often made using standard ports, like 443 for HTTPS. The front-end or reverse proxy is often also strips HTTPS, so the communication with the client happens securely, but the communication of the front-end with the real service is done unencrypted (so quick). Virtual hosts (in Apache terminology) or servers (in Nginx terminology) are the nice way way to route to different services by name; another way to do that is to use different prefixes in URI paths.
That way, it doesn't matter which ports they are listening on private, because public clients never see or even know them.
So, I suspect, it is not very good setup, that clients directly access the private API on a non-standard port. Though, it is impossible for the remote system to access the service bound to localhost, so I presume you are misunderstanding something here or not telling the whole situation to us.
